# Pass Array to List in Controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

This is Jquery code.In this i am trying to pass formlist to the formlist List of Class FormDetail.cs

```
  $("#btnPrintAll").click(function () {
    var formlist = [];
    var empcd = $("#ddlEmp").val();

    $(".frmcheck:checked").each(function () {
        formlist.push({
            FormID: $(this).data("formid"),
            Area: $(this).data("area"),
            Controller: $(this).data("controller"),
            Action: $(this).data("action"),
            empcd: empcd
        });

    });

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Getallviews", "PCM", new { area = "PBPCM" })',
        type: "Get",
        datatype: "HTML",
        data: { form: formlist },
        contentType: 'application/json;',
        success: function (result) {
            $("#dialog").html(result);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Something Went Wrong. Please try after some time.");
        }
    });
});
```

This Is FormDetail.cs

```
public class FormDetail
    {
        public string empcd { get; set; }
        public string FormName { get; set; }
        public string FormID { get; set; }
        public string Area { get; set; }
        public string Controller { get; set; }
        public string Action { get; set; }
        public List<FormDetail> formlist { get; set; }
    }
```

This is action in Controller

```
 public ActionResult Getallviews(List<FormDetail> form)
        {
            FormDetail model=new FormDetail();
            model.formlist = form;
            return PartialView("_pdfOfAllForms",model);
        }
```

I am getting Count=2 in form list in Controller, but all the null values. Please tell me where I am wrong.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Change it to `type: "Post",`

Comment: Thanks alot. It worked. But i am confused that am trying to get partial view that's why I used get and HTML  ,type and datatype. Why we used post here??

Comment: The `Content-Type` header is not used when making a GET. It needs to be a POST (or you would need to generate the values with indexers - `data: { [0].FormID: someValue, [1].FormID: anotherValue, etc },`. But its unclear what your trying to do here - your appear to just sending back the same values that the controller sent to the view - what is the point? You should be just sending back an array of the `ID` values.

Comment: I have a forms List that need to print on click of one print button. These Forms individually works fine. But what is need to do is to make a list of forms and each form row has one checkbox. User can check on the checkboxes that forms he need to print. Then only selected forms should print. So I am sending the selected forms and data like area,controller and action and used a partial view that is rendering all the Partial Views of Individual Forms. Hope you understood.

Comment: Yes, and its a poor design. Do not send a whole lot of extra data to the view and then send it back again all unchanged. You could simple have `<input name="selected" type="checkbox" value="@item.FormId" />` and use `data: $('form').serialize()` which would bind to a parameter `string[] selected` Then you get the objects based on the ID's in the parameter.

Comment: here in data i m getting selected&1, suppose 1 is fromID, But after that it shows error "Invalid JSON primitive: selected".